# GAE blobs disappearing when developing local

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, blobstore

So I am I am using java and maven and having an issue with my local google app engine, where i upload an image via the blobstore apis but then can not server the image back out, after restarting the app engine. An image uploaded, can be served prior to the restart.

What i think is happening is that the blob store is being cleared out when i restart (via the mvn clean). I had the same issue with the data store but fixed that by moving the data store file via a command line arg (-Ddatastore.backing_store)

What i can not find for the life of me is the proper command line arg for setting where the blob store is located. I think that if i set that my images would still be available to me.

Answer (score 0):

ehhhhhhh... i feel like i could have found this before posting... but it was in a really [weird spot](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting/javadoc/constant-values).

The argument is blobstore.backing_store

i hope this helps someone tho.